# Error in an @angular/cli project using TweenMax library

Tags: angular, gsap

I've integrated the gsap library with an @angular/cli project using .angular-cli.json as the method shown here

```
installed the gsap package using the npm
add the uncompressed source file into the scripts section of the angular configuration.s
```

```
 **"scripts": ["node_modules/gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js"]**
```

app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {Power1, Bounce} from 'gsap/all';
declare var TweenMax: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('mushroom') box: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.doIt();
  }

  doIt(): void {
    TweenMax.fromTo(this.box.nativeElement, 2, { x: 20 }, { x: 440, ease: Power1.easeOut });
    TweenMax.fromTo(this.box.nativeElement, 1, {y:20}, {y: 440, ease:Bounce.easeOut})
  }
}
```

error show is

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're loading [GSAP 3](http://greensock.com/3) and you're trying to treat it like it's GSAP 2. GSAP 3 has no Max/Lite files (and we don't recommend using the Max/Lite syntax either). We recommend using [the GSAP 3 installation page](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Installation) to help you get up and running.

In terms of learning GSAP 3 syntax, use [the GSAP 3 Migration Guide](https://greensock.com/3-migration).

Note that there's currently [a bug in the Angular build tool](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/22140-angular-7-gsap-3-failed-to-perform-build-production-aot/) which may prevent you from building for production but that's not a GSAP issue.

Comment: Thanks For your help I got what was missing and able to resolve my issue by `npm install --save gsap@2.1.3`,but why is the Max/Lite syntax not recommended

Comment: GSAP 3 has a ***bunch*** of new features, a smaller file size, and a sleeker API so there's not any reason to use an older version of GSAP for new projects :) For a full write up, check out the links I provided.